# How to strapi + react fullstack app on one server?

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I want set up a fullstack app with strapi and react. All tutorials i've seen say to deploy frontend on netlify and backend to something like heroku. Is there a posibility to deploy full app at one hosting?

I mean user entering website will get react app and backend will be running at onother port on the same hosing

Answer (score 0):

You can host both the front end(react) and backend(strapi) on heroku.
they can be hosted as two different individual apps running on different dynos and they can even be hosted as a single app together.
see this answer:
[How to deploy Strapi backend and ReactJS frontend to a single Heroku app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63118276/how-to-deploy-strapi-backend-and-reactjs-frontend-to-a-single-heroku-app)

Answer (score -1):

You definitely *can* deploy both on the same server, the question is whether you *should* do that.

What if your system has another client, like mobile app? Or what if you have more than one API server, and several databases (e.g. mongo and redis)? You don't want to put all of them on a single server, do you? By deploying them separately you can benefit from horizontal scaling, i.e. you upgrade your hosting plan on particular server whenever it needs more resources, without affecting another nodes. Divide and rule!

If you still want to deploy React and back-end on the same server, the better place for that would be something like DigitalOcean. On single droplet you can place as many servers as you want and configure them to launch on different ports.