# Deploy strapi and react js to heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

I have strapi as backend and react js as frontend developed in separate folders. When doing the development from localhost I have to run `npm start` for both strapi and react js which both running in two different port.

The thing is, I've been asked to deploy my project to heroku but I have no idea on the deployment process as there is no specific tutorial that I can find for that matter. I found this similar issue as mine here [How to deploy Strapi backend and ReactJS frontend to a single Heroku app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63118276/how-to-deploy-strapi-backend-and-reactjs-frontend-to-a-single-heroku-app) but the solutions given are not clear to follow.

Should I put the strapi and react js in one folder and add the middlewares like in the solution given then only deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to get a CLI instalation on your machine. After that you need to Login on heroku with the following command:

```
$ heroku login
```

After you've done this step you need to clone the repository or the remote location in case you have already a git repo on your localmachine as such.

Remember that before this you need to create a Heroku App on heroku.com first. then follow the step.

```
$ heroku git:clone -a [my-repository-name]
```

after you are done with this. Commit your project files. as such.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "my first project commit front end"
$ git push heroku master
```

You need to make sure that you have a procfile that is needed in order to run the npm run command. so.. create a file called.

*Procfile*

> (this is the name of the file that needs to be behind src file.

After you have done this. You may  continue with the next project. example. this would work only for your frontend application. For the backend application you can create another application and repeat the same steps.

```
web: npm run start
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I've already done all of the steps you mentioned above. I just want to highlight your last point. Are you suggesting that I should just create two app in my heroku, one for strapi (backend) and one for react js (frontend), and let them both run in separate url?

Comment: @Leon yes... backend one app then frontend other app and change urls of your back on the frontend. recommend using enviroment variables for this so you can use them on heroku and locally and not worry about it. :D